# Java method for counting number of bits in a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit-manipulation

I can't find a useful answer for this in relation to Java here or on the web in general. The problem is seemingly simple - I need a way of counting the number of bits contained in a byte array of arbitrary size. The byte array can hold hex, decimal or binary values.

I'm sure this is one of those questions that will have me kicking myself when I see an answer, but it's proving extremely frustrating. The method should look something like:

```
public int bitsInByteArray(byte[] b) {
    return - sum of bit count (ie the sum total bits, not the sum of their values) 
    of each byte in b
}
```

Any direction or advice would be immensely appreciated.

EDIT - Apologies guys, I didn't word this right at all. I'm doing a crypto assignment, and have been asked to "encrypt a single block containing 64 zero bits using AES with the key k"
Now, I created 
    byte[] zeroBlockAes =  {0x0,0x0...0x0} until it contains 64 zero elements.
The problem is, this is a 512 bits surely? So should I just put eight zero values in?

When I do this, my encrypted output is 
    -75 111 69  107 -18 88  51  89  68  -123    -49 18  -26
    -109    94  21

And when I decrypt again I get my original eight zeros. Is this normal in AES or am I possibly doing something wrong, I thought block ciphers produced the same size input / output for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: return b.length *8;

Comment: What do you mean, a byte array holds bytes and nothing else. What is a "hex value", even?

Comment: Do you have any doubt in the equation: - `1 byte = 8 bits`? Then ask it directly, rather than framing a random question out of it.

Comment: What if the OP means "the number of 1-bits in the array"? That makes more sense.

Comment: @harold Quote OP: "not the sum of their values"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it wouldn't be the sum of their values.

Comment: @harold It wouldn't be only if you modify the meaning of a "bit value", which is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh I see, you interpreted "their" as referring to the bits, as opposed to the bytes. Well we'll see. OP should clarify.

Comment: @harold There's a solid chance we won't see a thing :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I guess you were right about the meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that **1 byte** equals **8 bits**, which Java defines in `Byte.SIZE`, we can write:

```java
 public int bitsInByteArray(final byte[] b) {
     return b.length * Byte.SIZE;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

as others have already said, if it's a byte array then the answer is to multiply the length by 8 since a byte is always 100% guaranteed to be 8 bits.

However, if you have an array of other types (ints, longs, etc) then you're kind of stuck because Java doesn't have a sizeOf method, which would give the the byte size of a given type.

These types are *usually standardized now, but of course they *could still vary from place to place (it's extremely unlikely), so you couldn't guarantee how much memory, precisely, they're occupying.

Is this a homework assignment? If not... you're probably doing something wrong, if you're asking this question about java.

Comment: On the other hand, Java has a handful of rigidly specified types so there's no need for sizeof.

Comment: int = 4 byte, long = 8 byte, boolean = 1 byte, float = 4 byte, double = 8 byte, short = char = 2 byte.